# Putting strings with tabs into Ace editor?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, ace-editor

I have an ace editor embedded in my web page, and I want to save/load a string of code from the database and plug it into ace editor with `editor.setValue(sometext)`

The code string in my db is like `public class Solution {\n\t\n}`, and in my page.js I have the following code to inject the string into editor:

`editor.setValue("<%= @submission.source_code.inspect[1..-2] %>", 1);`

where `@submission.source_code` is the code I want, and I used `.inspect` in ruby to get rid of the &quot thing.

But if I modify the code in editor and save, the next time I load the code from db it just fits every line into same line with many spaces. So I wonder how can I save the code into db and make it still have the same format for the next load?

Here's my code for the page with editor:

```
<%= form_for(@submission, url: save_path) do |f| %>
  <pre id="editor" style="height: 86vh; margin-bottom: 0px"></pre>
  <%= f.text_field :source_code, id: :submission_source_code %>
  <%= f.number_field :assignment_id, id: :submission_assignment_id, style: "display: none", :value => @assignment.id %>
<% end %>

<script>
  var editor = ace.edit("editor");
  var input = $('input[id="submission_source_code"]').hide();
  editor.setTheme("ace/theme/xcode");
  editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/java");
  editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
  editor.setOptions({fontSize: "14px"});
  editor.setValue("<%= @submission.source_code.inspect[1..-2] %>", 1);
  editor.getSession().on('change', function() {
    input.val(editor.getSession().getValue());
    console.log(input.val());
  });
</script>
```

For example, when I save the following code:

```
public class Solution {
    public int fib(int n) {
        return n;
    }
}
```

it becomes this:

[image: Saved text]

Comment: Can you provide a working demo of the problem you are facing?

Comment: Everything looks fine here, I guess you need to convert "<%= @submission.source_code.inspect[1..-2] %>" to the text format. Could you try to convert the "<%= @submission.source_code.inspect[1..-2] %>" using .html() and then try to display in the editor.

Comment: Hi Harsha, thx for the reply! I fixed it using raw() in ruby, which is pretty similar to what you suggested. Another fix is that I changed the hidden input field to a textarea, so that the tabs can be saved.